# SpecFlow+LivingDoc build step failing on remotely deployed test run

Tags: .net, specflow

I have a series of tests deployed to various remote machines, all running build agents locally on them.

The tests pass and complete, but the SpecFlow+ build step that creates the living doc fails with the following error

> *Error: Command failed: dotnet C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\CLI\LivingDoc.CLI.dll feature-folder "C:\AutoTests\SpecTests" --project-language "en" --output "C:\vstsagent\A1_work\r1\a\14319\FeatureData.json" --output-type JSON --title "AutoTestChrome2"
> 'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:481:13)
> at Object.execSync (child_process.js:521:13)
> at C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:116:46
> at step (C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:44:23)
> at Object.next (C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:25:53)
> at C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:19:71
> at __awaiter (C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:15:12)
> at C:\vstsagent\A1_work_tasks\SpecFlowPlus_32f3fe66-8bfc-476e-8e2c-9b4b59432ffa\0.6.672\index.js:76:12
> at Object. (C:\vstsagent\A1_w*

I have installed *dotnet core 3.1* on the local machine. When I run `dotnet --version` in the command prompt, I get `3.1.404` as the returned value.

I had seen this issue in github [SpecFlow doesn't work with .NET Core 3.1.200 SDK](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1912)

The issue does seem to be resolved, but I am getting the same error. It does say to use `MSBUILDSINGLELOADCONTEXT=1 as an env var, but I'm not sure where that would go in the build step if in case it should.

The project I am testing is using *Speclfow + Selenium + MsBuild* and is written using *.NET Framework 4.7.2*

As an aside, we are running Azure Devops 2019 on a self hosted installation, and, when I open the *Speclow + livingdoc* page in devops, I get the following message

> SpecFlow+LivingDoc is taking longer than expected to load.

It does load, but there is nothing to see (for obvious reasons :) )

Answer (score 0):

Good news is I got it working

As these servers are virtuals, I had been restarting them myself from the machine. I finally got our server department to do a machine reboot for me, and now the livingdoc is working. Obviously it needs this hard reboot for …. Well, windows